# JTable id resetting after dynamic search

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable, row

I have a jtable that comes from MySQL database in my app like in this image;

[image]

When i pick a row, i show its id number on left bottom as it seems in above image. Then i will send that id to somewhere so i need it. But i also have a dynamic search for my table, i make a search like in this image;

[image]

I filter search the ones that starts with 'Go' letter, it shows 2 movies and their qualifications are correct but it doesn't give its correct id when i pick one. As it seems in image, i pick Good Time movie, its id is 7 but left bottom says 1, if i pick Gora movie, its id is 8 but left bottom says 2. But i want left bottom shows the id of the movie.

In my code, i think these methods will be useful to understand my error (DefaultTableModel model; is initialized at start of the class);

My Jdialog's constructor;

```
public JDialogClass(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal, int id) {
    super(parent, modal);
    initComponents();
    this.kullaniciID = id;
    model = (DefaultTableModel) myTable.getModel();
    showTable();
}
```

showTable method;

```
public void showTable(){
    model.setRowCount(0);

    ArrayList<Programlar> programlar = new ArrayList<Programlar>();

    programlar = islemler.programGetir();
    if(programlar != null){
        for(Programlar program:programlar){
            Object[] tabloicerigi = {program.getId(),program.getAd(),program.getTur(),program.getTip(),program.getBolumsayisi(),
                                            program.getUzunluk(),program.getPuan()};
            model.addRow(tabloicerigi);
        }

    }

}
```

Dynamic Search method;

```
public void dynamicSearch(String arama){

    TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel> tr = new TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel>(model);

    myTable.setRowSorter(tr);

    tr.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + arama, 1)); // 1 number here means search in 2nd column of table

}
```

KeyReleased method for dynamicSearch;

```
private void searchKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                            

    String arama = search.getText();

    dynamicSearch(arama);

}
```

and Selected row method;

```
private void myTableMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                            
    int selectedRow = myTable.getSelectedRow();

    int selectedId = (int) model.getValueAt(selectedRow, 0);
    labelWhichShowsID.setText(String.valueOf(selectedId)); 

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
myTable.setRowSorter(tr);
```

You are sorting the data in the JTable.

The data in the model is NOT sorted. The JTable just displays the data in a sorted view.

```
int selectedId = (int) model.getValueAt(selectedRow, 0);
```

So the above statement is incorrect since the model index may not match the table row index.

You could get the data directly from the table:

```
int selectedId = (int) myTable.getValueAt(selectedRow, 0);
```

However, this has the potential that the user may have reorganized the columns (unless your have disabled this functionality) and column 0 of the table view will no longer be the id.

So the safer solution is to use:

```
int modelRow = myTable.convertRowIndexToModel(selectedRow);
int selectedId = (int) model.getValueAt(modelRow, 0);
```